# Find My iPhone App

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud

I wonder if it is possible to create an ios app to check whether "Find My iPhone" is enabled or not in iCloud? Is there any way I can access this and get the info of it. Please help

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Due to app sandboxing, and security issues, no such thing is possible, at least not on a non-jailbroken iPhone.